# Real-world examples of Darwinian extinction

Tags: evolution, life-history, extinction

Darwinian extinction (also known as "evolutionary suicide") refers to processes of selection-driven self-extinction, i.e. the cases where natural selection causes the extinction of an evolving population.

In the literature, there are many models of life-history evolution and (to a lesser extent) experiments with bacteria in which Darwinian extinction has been demonstrated. However, I couldn't find anywhere real-world examples (i.e. not from models or experiments) of Darwinian extinction of complex organisms within more or less constant environment.

Do we know of such examples?
And if we do, could you please refer me to them?

**Edit:** A mechanism of the Darwinian extinction could be, for example, the emergence of ”selfish” strategies w.r.t frequency-dependent selection, which are beneficial to individuals when rare, but may result in a deteriorating environment and smaller population size once they become common.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something like an example of [mutational meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutational_meltdown) or an example of a selfish genetic element driving extinction. In short an example of extinction that is of particular interest to evolutionary and conservation geneticists. I think the current answers (despite one being generously upvoted) do not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Although you don't mention it in your question, I guess you'd like examples of extinction in (more or less) constant environment? Then I guess you'd like cases of extinction due to the introduction of an overseas species out-competing the original one.

Red squirrel is not extinct yet, but its sharp population decrease is mostly linked with competition with newly introduced grey squirrel, although habitat loss and concurrent introduction of a virus are also part of the causes. Read at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_squirrel

Comment: It could be worth noting that the most important component of the decline is actually squirrelpox virus, which causes subclinical infection in greys but kills reds.

Comment: Well, wouldn't resistance to pathogens be part of Darwinian fitness? Although it is true that the virus is reported to have been introduced along with grey squirrels, thus it's difficult to decouple the population reduction due to its introduction and the interspecies competition.

Comment: Yes, constant environment. And thank you for the example, looks promising. But I was more interested in ”selfish” strategies w.r.t frequency-dependent selection, if you know of any such examples. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Joce Differential pathogen resistance is **part off** interspecies competition.

Comment: Yes, but what I meant is that if the pathogen is introduced (or exposition increased) at a given time, this is modifying the fitness of the species independently of interspecies competition. Thus part of the adjustment in population size may be a response of this new environment only (and would be obtained for same exposure to virus w/o the competing species presence)

Comment: @joce it would, yes. 'Competition' is a broad description of what is happening; I'm just suggesting this answer might be improved by a more specific description of the mechanism.

Comment: @Joce ''this is modifying the fitness of the species independently of interspecies competition'. No, the differential response to the same pathogen between species **is not independent from** interspecies competition but **part of** interspecies competition. -1

Comment: @AlexDeLarge: have you read my comment? If the introduction of the pathogen is concurrent to the introduction of the competing species, then you could have extinction of gray squirrel without any competition, simply by epidemics. If the pathogen was already present, then you are right that the population diminution can be read as the outcome of the interspecies competition.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge: As this is not appropriate for a comment, I have started a new question to discuss this. See http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/49246/interspecies-competition-and-pathogen

Answer (score 0):

It hard to find example like that because evolutionary suicide does not mean it must end with extinction

I think this 2 words is not equal. Member of every specie would evolve into something disadvantage to specie as a whole, but then it would rapidly lead to equilibrium and/or evolution arm race before extinct

I could say most predator evolve to starve their specie, if they have many offspring then the prey would all gone and they will starve to death as a whole. But before all prey die the predator would gradually fall and the prey member will rise up again into equilibrium

There are also specie that develop infanticide or cannibalism. But before that specie gone extinct the group that develop those trait would have decrease, those group would gone extinct before the whole specie, or at least some group without those trait would have better chance to survive

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. And by definition, Darwinian extinction results in extinction.

Comment: @101010111100 Darwinian extinction is extinction but evolutionary suicide is not the same word

Answer (score 0):

The loss of self-incompatibility (gaining the ability to breed with oneself) in the Nightshade family has been demonstrated to result in both a higher diversification rate and an even higher extinction rate, overall leading to a lower diversification rate in self-compatible lineages.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.702.1437&rep=rep1&type=pdf